# How can I index an exact value repeated in multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This application is to list what *racks* a item would be located in a warehouse.

For example if an item was stored on a few different racks. I don't need a total of how many times the item is repeated, just the column header in this case "Rack #" where it could be found.

I created a simple example and need the code for B2.

I just entered the value of B2 to show the result I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Don't we all "just need the code" for something? -- Seriously, this is a website where people will help you with a specific problem on a detailed level, _after_ you've shown that you tried to solve it and where you failed.

Comment: How many racks do you have in your real data?

Comment: Unfortunately this application is for a large warehouse where there would be 102 racks/coloums. I was looking for an efficient way to list what racks an item might be found in so they can re-organize our inventory. Most likely a singe code/item would only be found in 1 or 2 different Racks at most.  @Class Stacker My excel knowledge is minimal and after a while on Youtube and other sites like this I have not found a solution. I appreciate everyone's helpful responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tricky solution without using VBA

- Insert `=""` into G2:G6.
- Insert `=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH($A2,D$2:D$5,0))),CONCATENATE(G2,IF(G2="","",", "),D$1),G2)` into H2 and copy it to H2:J6
- Insert `=J2` into B2 and copy it into B2:B6

[image: Solution to Questions]

If you add racks you need to add columns right of the J column.

[image: More Racks and more content in the Racks]

If there would be a nice string concatenate function in Excel one could shorten it ... .

## Explanation

We need to put `=""` into the G column because I wanted to have the same code in the columns H to J and no extra if clauses.

The long command explained:

- In which row is A2 in the column D2:D5 (if not present then #NA) => MATCH(A2,D2:D5,0)
- Is A2 not in the column D2:D5 => ISNA(MATCH(A2,D2:D5,0))
- Invert "Is A2 not in the column D2:D5" => NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A2,D2:D5,0)))
- If the above happens then do THIS else do THAT => IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A2,D2:D5,0))),THIS,THAT)
- THIS (A2 is in the Column = we want to have "Rack 1" written down) => CONCATENATE(G2,IF(G2="","",", "),D1)
- THAT (we have nothing new) => G2

Answer (score -1):

Here it is, using VBA / Macros:

```
Public Function racks(code As String, range As range) As String
    result = ""
    Separator = ","
    colRanges = range.Columns.Count
    rowRanges = range.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To colRanges
        For j = 2 To rowRanges
            If code = range.Cells(j, i) Then
                If result <> "" Then
                    result = result & Separator & range.Cells(1, i)
                Else
                    result = range.Cells(1, i)
                End If
                j = rowRanges
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    racks = result
End Function
```

Open VBA/Macros with Alt+F11, insert a new module under *ThisWorkbook*, and paste this code on the right side.

The function use two parameters, the *code* and the *range* where it will do the search.

For example, for cell *B2*  on your example it will be `=racks(A2,$D$1:$F$5)`.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your in depth response! I didn't think there would be such a quick response.